# What does an ampersand mean when assigning a variable? (Java)

Tags: java, variables, declaration, ampersand

What does the ampersand mean in this code?

```
int clothes = (random.nextInt(0x1000000) & 0x7f7f7f);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the [*bitwise AND*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operator#AND) operator.

It operates on each bit position independently; the output bit in position *n* is only 1 if both the corresponding input bits in position *n* are also 1.

In this context, the `0x7f7f7f` is being used as a [*bit-mask*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_mask).  By having certain bit positions as 0, it means that the corresponding bit positions in `clothes` will *always* be 0.  All other bit positions will take on the same value as produced by `random.nextInt(0x1000000)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit it clears things up muchly!